# Do I need recompile third party libraries if I make a small change to the header file

Tags: c++

I got a third party library. This library has a class. And this class declare all its data members as protected. Because I need to access the data members of this class from my own code, I have modified "protected" to "public".

Now I can access the data members of this third-party class without recompiling the third-party library.

Therefore, my conclusion is that key words such as "public", "protected" and "private" does not go into the compiled code. The scope of these keywords are confined to the header files.
We can change "private" and "protected" to "public" in order to access the class data members.

Is my conclusion right or wrong? Please help.

Comment: You usually shouldn't change 3rd party stuff, and yes you'll need to recompile!

Comment: If you pass that class instance to the third party DLL, you'll have problems

Comment: `Because I need to access the data members of this class from my own code, I have modified "protected" to "public"`  Why not derive your own class from this class?  Then all of those `protected` members will become available in your derived class.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: and being C++ you can expose mutable references to those... `protected` should never be used for data members for this reason, it's as good as `public`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The third-party code is returning a third-party class object. I cannot access the protected members of this third-party object. Deriving the third-party class does not help.

Answer (score 13):

> Do I need recompile third party libraries if I make a small change to the header file

**Yes, absolutely.**

Access rules are only applied at compile-time and do not live on in your compiled executable. However, they have a huge influence on the *memory layout* of your type, and this influence lives on right through compilation, into your executable and ultimately into RAM on the executing computer.

> `[C++11: 9.2/14]:` Non-static data members of a (non-union) class with the same access control (Clause 11) are allocated so that later members have higher addresses within a class object. The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified (11). *[..]*

With this in mind, consider the following:

```
struct T
{
private:
   int x;
public:
   int y;
   int z;
};
```

It is unspecified as to how `x` and `y` will appear in memory with respect to each other, but `z` will always be found after `y` (because they share an access level). So, one possible ordering that your compiler may come up with is this:

```
y z x
```

Now if you were to change `x` so that it is also `public`:

```
struct T
{
public:
   int x;
   int y;
   int z;
};
```

…that previous ordering is no longer allowed; in fact, the *only* ordering allowed is now:

```
x y z
```

Seeing as a change in the layout of a type breaks binary compatibility, this is a massively significant change to your compiled program: at the very least, you would have to rebuild the whole project; at worst, as here, it's a library, so you must also increment whichever version number you're using to denote binary interface changes (to prevent horrible access violations and hard-to-spot bugs) and propagate the new dependency to all dependent projects.

Anyway, to do this to a third party library seems like a smell right from the outset. Either it has a very poor interface that is not fit for purpose (in which case, use a different one or fork it properly by *improving the interface*), or you're doing something horribly wrong.

Comment: According to the standard, you're right, but in practice, I don't know of any compiler which doesn't lay the members out in the order they are declared, independently of the access.  (But I still wouldn't do what he proposed.  Your last paragraph is right on.)

Answer (score 0):

You are playing with fire!  *All bets are off*!  This is indefined behaviour: it may work as expected, it might also raid your ice-box.

Comment: Where is the undefined behaviour?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: I am trying to encourage this author to explain that in the answer. Right now it's just an assertion.